# How to make a picture appear from a list and make it disappear, while setting a variable to it in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering how would I get an image to appear out of a list and then make it disappear once it is clicked on. And once it is clicked on a variable will be assigned.

When I run this in pygame I get a bunch all of these pictures printed and they go by really fast.

```
def game():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1400, 750))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Goofspiel")
    screenExit = False
    while not screenExit:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                screenExit = True

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

        screen.fill(lightgray)

        fontname = pygame.font.SysFont("Denmark", 150)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Denmark", 40)
        font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("Denmark", 75)

        name = fontname.render("Goofspeil", True, (black))
        score = font.render("Player 1", True, (blue))
        score1 = font.render("Player 2", True, (red))
        player = font1.render("Player 1", True, (black))
        que = font.render("Who's turn is it?", True, (black))


        screen.blit(name, (490, 0))

        #Score board
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, sun, [0,20,375,80])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [0,20,375,5])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [0, 100.5, 375, 5])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [375, 20, 5, 85])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [305, 20, 5, 85])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [180, 20, 5, 85])
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, black, [110, 20, 5, 85])

        screen.blit(score, (0, 50))
        screen.blit(score1, (190, 50))
        screen.blit(que, (1100, 20))
        screen.blit(player, (1120, 70))

        #Displaying the cards
        screen.blit(DK, (5, 450))
        screen.blit(DQ, (100, 450))
        screen.blit(DJ, (200, 450))
        screen.blit(D10, (300, 450))
        screen.blit(D9, (400, 450))
        screen.blit(D8, (500, 450))
        screen.blit(D7, (600, 450))
        screen.blit(D6, (700, 450))
        screen.blit(D5, (800, 450))
        screen.blit(D4, (900, 450))
        screen.blit(D3, (1000, 450))
        screen.blit(D2, (1100, 450))
        screen.blit(D1, (1200, 450))

        #Add a random picture
        list = []
        list.append(HK)
        list.append(HQ)
        list.append(HJ)
        list.append(H10)
        list.append(H9)
        list.append(H8)
        list.append(H7)
        list.append(H6)
        list.append(H5)
        list.append(H4)
        list.append(H3)
        list.append(H2)
        list.append(H1)

        #rand = random.randrange(0, len(list))
        random.shuffle(list)
        screen.blit(list[0], (700,150))

        if 200 > mouse[0] > 100 and 700 > mouse[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, lightblue2, [80, 705, 200, -60])
            if click[0] == 1:

                x = 12
                score2 = font.render(str(x), True, (black))
                screen.blit(score2, (135, 50))


        pygame.display.update()

game()
```

What I want to do, is that I want a picture randomly out of this list to show up, then get "removed" from the list and then make the picture disappear from the screen. Because these pictures are cards, I want that if a person clicks on the king, the `x` value = 13 and so on.

Can someone please help, I'm stuck on this question. I'm trying to make the game [Goofspiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goofspiel) and I can't!

Comment: What sort of structure / class are `HK`, `HQ`, `HJ`, etc.?  Do they "know" their own locations?

Comment: Oh yeah I should've included that they are pictures. HK would stand for King of Hearts and so on. I used pygame.image.load("Kingofhearts.png") and so on for each of them.

Comment: The code you show should only display one image. Do you have some kind of loop that you aren't showing? Also: have you considered that if you want multiple images to be visible at once, you can't draw them all in the same place?

Comment: I have updated my code and posted the whole thing so you could see what I was doing, or trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a point-form of how I would proceed:

- Convert your H1, H2 ... images into [PyGame Sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61091199/1730895).

This melds an image with a rectangle.  It allows you to easily re-position and draw all the cards.  The code an also use the mouse-click event to easily determine which of the cards (if any) was clicked.

- Add the necessary card details into the Sprite Class too

This allows your Card to "know" its suit, number, and whether it's face-up.

- Put your Card Sprites into a Pygame [SpriteGroup](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group)

This facilitates easy drawing and mouse-click collision detection.

- Once you know which card was clicked, it's pretty easy to remove it from the screen, turn it over, whatever because its state (location, suit, number, face-up, etc.) is all kept together in the sprite class.  It no longer becomes a question of removing "#8 from the list".

Something like this:

```
class Card( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):

    def __init__( self, front_image, back_image, suit, number, facing_up=True ):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.front       = pygame.image.load( front_image ).convert()
        self.back        = pygame.image.load( back_image ).convert()
        self.rect        = self.front.get_rect()
        self.suit        = suit
        self.number      = number
        self.face_up     = not facing_up
        self.flip()      # re-draw

    def flip( self ):
        self.face_up = not self.face_up
        if ( self.face_up ):
            self.image = self.front
        else:
            self.image = self.back

    def moveTo( self, x, y ):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def isFaceUp( self ):
        return self.face_up

    # ... etc.


# make the cards
HK  = Card( 'hearts_king.png',  'card_back.png', 'hearts', 13 )
HQ  = Card( 'hearts_queen.png', 'card_back.png', 'hearts', 12 )
HJ  = Card( 'hearts_jack.png',  'card_back.png', 'hearts', 11 )
H10 = Card( 'hearts_10.png',    'card_back.png', 'hearts', 10 )
# ... etc
all_hearts = [ HK, HQ, HJ, H10, H9, ... H1 ]

# TODO: call Card.moveTo() to position each card

cards_on_table = pygame.sprite.Group()
for card in all_hearts:
    cards_on_table.add( card )


# Main Loop:
while not done:
    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP ):
            # On mouse-click
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Did we click on a card?
            for card in cards_on_table:
                if ( card.rect.collidepoint( mouse_pos ) ):
                    print( "Card [%s, %d] was clicked" % ( card.suit, card.number ) )
                    cards_on_table.remove( card )  # remove card from group
                    break


    # Re-draw the window
    window.fill( DARK_GREEN )
    cards_on_table.draw( window )
    pygame.display.flip()
    # ... etc
```

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks for the quick reply I will do this and if I run into a problem I will ask here. Thank you so much though, I'll start coding this now.

Comment: @20sniper03 - sure, no worries.