# How do I make my buttons, objects, etc. size DEPENDENT on the window size?

Tags: python, windows, pygame, image-resizing

I know how to make the window resizable, but if I run the code only the window get's resized. The buttons, objects, etc. don't. What do I have to do to make them get resized dependent of the window? If this question is somehow hard to understand you can go to my question where I asked how to make the window resize and read the comments there. Here's the code, just if you guys need it:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

WINDOW_WIDTH = 800
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600

SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)
win.fill((0, 180, 210))

pygame.display.set_caption("Baloon War!")
icon = pygame.image.load("Baloon war icon.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

centre_point = (WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2)

class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text=''):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text

    def draw(self, win, outline=None):
        # Call this method to draw the button on the screen
        if outline:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, outline, (self.x - 2, self.y - 2, self.width + 4, self.height + 4), 0)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height), 0)

        if self.text != '':
            font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 60)
            text = font.render(self.text, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            win.blit(text, (self.x + (self.width / 2 - text.get_width() / 2), self.y + (self.height / 2 - text.get_height() / 2)))

    def isOver(self, pos):
        # Pos is the mouse position or a tuple of (x,y) coordinates
        if pos[0] > self.x and pos[0] < self.x + self.width:
            if pos[1] > self.y and pos[1] < self.y + self.height:
                return True

        return False

    def rescale(self):
        new_size = int(WINDOW_WIDTH * self.scale_factor)
        x, y = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.original, (new_size, new_size))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (x, y)

def redrawMenuWindow():
    win.fill((0, 255, 110))
    greenButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))
    redButton.draw(win, (0, 0, 0))

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.fill((0, 150, 210))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 250, 110),(0, 450, 800, 250))




greenButton = button((0, 255, 0), 280, 255, 250, 100, "Start")
redButton = button ((255, 0, 0), 280, 380, 250, 100, "Quit")

game_state = "menu"
run = True
while run:
    if game_state == "menu":
        redrawMenuWindow()
    elif game_state == "game":
        redrawGameWindow()
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            WINDOW_WIDTH = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            win = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT), SURFACE)

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the button")
                game_state = "game"
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                print("clicked the 2button")
                run = False
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            if greenButton.isOver(pos):
                greenButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                greenButton.color = (0, 255, 0)
            if redButton.isOver(pos):
                redButton.color = (105, 105, 105)
            else:
                redButton.color = (255, 0, 0)

        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()` command. You can read the documentation for it (Link: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen).
Here is an example code:

```
if event.key == K_f:
    pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
```

You do not have to do more. You could make a button on which you can press and then use this command. It is really easy to use. Hope I could help you, old me! :) I just found it today and so I wanted to answer so you and others can find this answer!

Comment: Thx, Future me! Really helped. It is useful to know that you only have to use this command and then Pygame resizes all the Sprites, etc. by the Windowsize.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will solve the issue hopefully, in your `Button` class (classes begin with capital letters), add this method:

```
def resize_button(self, width, height, x, y):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

then, in `main_loop` when you are catching the `VIDEORESIZE` event:

```
elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            win = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE)
            greenButton.resize_button(event.w*0.3, event.h*0.3, event.w/2, event.h/2)
```

Use coefficients to multiply parameters to get the desired results. Play around with this. But the main idea is to make button size and position relative to the current window size. 
Also insert the `clock.tick(FPS)` in your `main_loop` and don't forget to add `clock = pygame.clock.Time()` before the loop. This way you can control FPS leading to smaller processor usage.

Comment: it won't work :( 
Maybe look what I asked in my last question (How do I maximize and minimize my pygame window) and see what I got answered in the comment. Then you see what I should've done. Maybe...

Comment: @RMR_MD Could you elaborate why this doesn't work? Because this is how you do it. You have to manually resize all your images/buttons/widgets/sprite when the user resizes the window.

Comment: Exactly, certainly there are neater ways to do it, but this does work.

Comment: I tested it and it does resize the `greenButton`, as I said play around with coefficients and sizes to get desire result. I hope you will make it work as you want. If you need additional help, ask.

Comment: @kaktus_car , I tried it again and it worked better this time but there is one problem. The button will get bigger already event if i didn't resize the screen and when I resize it just makes matters worse. I'll update the question with the actual codes (= I will make two different codes).

Comment: @RMR_MD You forgot `WINDOW_WIDTH = event.w` and `WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h` look at the @Kingsley 's answer.

Comment: You edited the answer, but now you have removed the part with resizing buttons, you need to include both of these

Comment: ok. I don't remember what it was... do you mean that last part ```"rescale greenButton"```???

Comment: I think it was this ` greenButton.resize_button` you can look into the edit history

Answer (score 3):

What @kaktus_car answers is correct.  The code needs to respond to the window size, re-scaling on-screen elements accordingly.

The base problem with the OP's code is that the window size is "hard coded", and even when the re-size event is received, the new window size is forgotten.  This means the code does not know the size of the window, and thus cannot re-scale graphics/controls.

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)  # <-- FIXED SIZE

...

elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((event.w, event.h), pygame.RESIZABLE) # <-- NEW SIZE
```

This is relatively simple to fix.

The first step is to store the window size, and use it for scaling on-screen objects.  Don't have a "50x50" box, have a box 12% the width of the screen-width.
(The size can be retrieved from the surface every time, but I find this cumbersome.)

```
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 400
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 400

SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
```

This means doing some things a little harder than just inserting co-ordinates.  For example where is the centre of the window, not "200,200", but:

```
centre_point = ( WINDOW_WIDTH//2, WINDOW_HEIGHT//2 )
```

So later when the window-size event happens, these variables can simply be updated, and the on-screen objects scale to suit:

```
# Handle user-input
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
        done = True
    elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
        WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
        WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
        window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
```

If you have sprite objects, these can be re-scaled too.  Record the original size as a *scaling factor*.  When the window size increases or decreases, re-applying this factor in combination with the new size on the sprite bitmap rescales it accordingly.

```
class AlienSprite( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):

    def __init__( self, bitmap, x, y ):
        self.original     = bitmap
        self.image        = bitmap
        self.rect         = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center  = ( x, y )
        # Keep the existing scale factor from startup to preserve the size ratio
        self.scale_factor = self.rect.width / WINDOW_WIDTH

    def rescale( self ):
        new_size = int( WINDOW_WIDTH * self.scale_factor )  # new size
        x, y = self.rect.center                             # existing centre position
        # Re-size the bitmap
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale( self.original, ( new_size, new_size ) )
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = ( x, y )                         # restore to the centre point
```

When the `pygame.VIDEORESIZE` event happens:

```
    elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
        WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
        WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
        window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )

        for s in sprite_group:   # rescale all the sprites
            s.rescale()
```

Comment: there is no definitionn for s and spritegroup

Comment: @RMR_MD - Maybe something like:  `sprite_group =  pygame.sprite.Group()`, and a couple of  `sprite_group.add( AlienSprite( alien_image, 100, 100 ) )`.  `s` is created by the `for` loop.

Comment: Ok, but what does sprite mean/what are those? And how do I make this with the buttons???

Comment: @RMR_MD - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61088785/pygame-trying-to-understand-the-sprite-class/